# How to compile luaJit's c bytecode

Tags: c, lua, bytecode, jit, luajit

you can generate bytecode in form of c with luaJIT : `luajit -b main.lua main.c`
it generate a c code with no main so my guess is to link it. How to do that with mingw64?

Comment: The C form of bytecode is needed if you want to have the bytecode as array of bytes in your C program (so, just add you own code to `main.c`).  Probably it's not what you want.  What do you need exactly?  It's not clear from your question.  How do you want to run this bytecode?

Comment: To start a bytecode in a C program, use `luaL_dostring()`.  The example of minimal C program in [here](http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/minimal-lua-c-example.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what exactly that does.

LuaJIT does *not* compile your Lua source code into equivalent C code. It compiles it to Lua bye code, and encodes this binary data as a static C array, so you can include the byte code directly in a program that uses LuaJIT and have it as a single executable.